# FQL Facebook API return null value

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-fql

I have code to get pid all photo of page albums.

```
String query = "SELECT pid FROM photo WHERE aid='100891649965116_15801'";
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("method", "fql.query");
params.putString("query", query);
Utility.mAsyncRunner.request(null, params, new FQLRequestListener());
```

But result always null.. I think that my problem is that i have not access_token in my app.. How to do fix my problem, can you give me some examples code, thank

Activity code

```
public class TestBActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    Facebook facebook = new Facebook("386199591435293");

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        facebook.authorize(this, new DialogListener(){
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) { }

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) { }

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e) { }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {  }
        });

        Button btt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        btt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                String query = "SELECT pid FROM photo WHERE aid='100891649965116_15801'";
                Bundle params = new Bundle();
                params.putString("method", "fql.query");
                params.putString("query", query);      
                Utility.mAsyncRunner.request(null, params, new FQLRequestListener());               
            }
        });
   }

    public class FQLRequestListener extends BaseRequestListener{
        @Override
        public void onComplete(final String response, final Object state) {
           try {
                JSONArray json = new JSONArray(response);
                Log.d("tag", json.toString());
           } catch (JSONException e) {
                try {
                   JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
                   Log.d("tag2", json.toString());
                } catch (JSONException e1) {

                }
            }
        }

        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the [Authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) documentation explains how to connect to a user's account

Comment: i have created facebook app and logon by my account in android app, but query return null value. I have updated my question, thank for help

Comment: And do you have the user_photos permission?

Comment: all photo of album id = 100891649965116_15801 is public, i think don't have permission

Comment: something being visible on facebook.com doesn't mean your app can access it without the user's permission

Comment: I want get all photos of albums in fanpage. Fanpage is not mine. I have added user_photos permission (new String[] { "user_photos", "read_stream" }) .. but result isn't chance.

Comment: If it's not your page, you may need the read_stream permission on behalf of the user who is accessing the page - i'm not clear on how the permissions model works with page photos